# Is it possible to set volume presets based upon Android TV input source?

Tags: volume-control, android-tv

Is it possible to automatically set the volume to a specific level when switching input source on the Android TV? I have several input sources (cable box, PS3, PS4, ...) but the volume on PS4 is massively loud whilst the same volume on the cable box is ok.

I'd like to automatically adjust the volume when changing the input source but I'm not sure if that's even possible. Any solution is ok (installing an app for example).

Answer (score 1):

Currently There is no way to do so, as Android TV does not differentiate input sources based on the devices you use. You could alternately set different volume on different devices if possible.

After thinking for a while , it could be possible by writing a bit of code and rooting your Android TV. If you are using HDMI to connect the devices, the TV detects the Graphic Card used to display content, if you have different Graphic Cards in you devices this will be possible. You might get help on xda Developers